# Datetime returning different date to input

Tags: django, date, datetime, picker

I am having some issues with datetime and datepicker. I have a model form with 2 date picker field (To and From), the date can be selected and saved. The problem is, when I go to edit form, the dates seem to show up as either a day ahead/behind of input date or just show up the current date.

My model.py:

```
    from_when = DateTimeField(_('From'), blank=True, null=True)
    to_when = DateTimeField(_('To'), blank=True, null=True)
```

forms.py:

```
    class ScheduleForm(ModelForm):
      class Meta:
        model = Schedule
        fields = ['from_when', 'to_when',]       

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ScheduleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.name = 'scheduleform'
        self.title = _('Add/Edit Schedule')        
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.form_layout()

    def form_layout(self):
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
        Div(
            Div(                    
                Div(
                    # use the jQuery datepicker plugin, if available
                    Field('from_when', css_class='datepicker'),
                    # use the jQuery datepicker plugin, if available
                    Field('to_when', css_class='datepicker'),                        
                    css_class='span4',
                ),                    
                css_class='row-fluid',
            ),
        ),
    )

     def save(self, force_insert=False,
            force_update=False, *args, **kwargs):        
        course = super(ScheduleForm, self).save(
                commit=True, *args, **kwargs)

    return course
```

Any ideas why this problem may occur?

Comment: Are there any additional settings for datepicker js part?

Comment: No additional settings for the datepicker

Comment: Are the dates correctly saved into db?

Comment: As far as I can tell they are saving to the db. I ran a unit test for this and it seemed to pass

Comment: What plugin is it exactly?